# Ellipsize every line of TextView

Tags: android

Is there a way to have multiline TextView with long lines ellipsized at the end.

For example I have this text (lines separated by \n)

```
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Bbbbbbb
Cccccccccccc
Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
Eeeeeeeeee
```

Now I have the following result on small screens:

```
Aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaa
Bbbbbbb
Cccccccccccc
Ddddddddddddd
ddddddddddddd
dddd
Eeeeeeeeee
```

And I want it to look tike this:

```
Aaaaaaaaaa...
Bbbbbbb
Cccccccccccc
Dddddddddd...
Eeeeeeeeee
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18411726/1777090

Comment: Works like a magic. Thanks.
For those who not very common with regexps change the pattern to

`Pattern.compile("^.+?$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE + Pattern.MULTILINE);`

Comment: @Dimanoid Can you please post full solution?

Comment: It was 6 years ago, I don't even remember where I used this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ellipsize individual lines of a SpannableString in a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798981/ellipsize-individual-lines-of-a-spannablestring-in-a-textview)